# Looping through Python lists

Tags: python

I have a list that I need to strip the \n from each item to get it to match to another list. Is there an easier way than doing a loop script? and having to append to a whole new list?

```
special_chars = {"%20":"    ",
"%21":"!",
"%22":'"',
"%23":"#",
"%24":"$",
"%25":"%",
"%26":"&",
"%27":"'",
"%28":"(",
"%29":")",
"%2A":"*",
"%2B":"+",
"%2C":",",
"%2D":"-",
'%2E':".",
'%2F':"/",
'%3A':":",
'%3B':";",
'%3C':"<",
'%3D':"=",
'%3E':">",
'%3F':"?",
'%40':"@"}

file = "file.txt"
file_open  = open(file)
readlines = file_open.readlines()
parameter = []

for key in special_chars:
    for line in readlines:
        if key in line:
           replace_value = key

replaced_value = special_chars[replace_value]

for line in readlines:
    parameter.append(line.replace(replace_value, replaced_value))

for line in parameter:
  print line.rstrip("\n") ### This is the part that I am having issue s with
```

Comment: No idea; please show an example input and output.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: you can use a list-comprehension as as shortcut. Or do a regular loop to modify the list in-place, although generally you just create a new list in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
list(map(lambda x: x.strip('\n')))
```